# Why is 'me' sometimes not used as an object?

Tags: subject-vs-object-pronouns

So occasionally I'll see something like this:

```
– Who did this?  
– Me.
```

Sometimes they'll go a little further and say `Me. I did.`, but not always.

This is one I see often:

```
– Hey! You!
– Who? Me?
```

In cases like these, why is `me` used instead of `I`? Are these usages actually correct, or merely acceptable in informal English?

In the first case, I can maybe see it as a shortened/alternative form of `[the one] who did this was me`. Is this a correct sentence? Or should it be `the one who did this was I`?

As for the second case, I can kind of get it. The reply might be thought of as a condensed form of `Who are you calling out to? Me?`, which can be thought of as an alternative way of saying `Are you calling out to me?`, in which case the need for the object form is obvious.

Is my reasoning correct? Or is it just a rule that "me" is acceptable as a response to "who" clauses?

Comment: This is completely unscientific, but I think that for some reason, native speakers of English (AmE, at least) feel uncomfortable using the standalone *I*. Isolated, exposed, vulnerable, it seems to want to be anywhere else than where it's used. That's probably partly due to its normal role, which is at the beginning of a sentence or clause. *Me* mostly happens farther down the line. So when you put forms of address (questions, shouted commands, etc.) at the beginning of an exchange, it just "feels right" to use *me* to complete them. At least it does to **me**. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of the "me" in those cases as being a subject or object of anything. It's just a word used on its own by a speaker to refer to themselves. It doesn't really fit into sentence structure - because it's not in a sentence. You can imagine any sentence you like around it, but the practical fact is it's just a label for the first person.

Comment: I see. But in that case, couldn't 'I' also be used, since it's also a label for the first person? However, it sounds wrong. Is it just a matter of custom?

Comment: If you really get down to it, language is all about custom. Unlike some languages, English has no "official" correct version, so it's all about describing what people do. *Me* is the word we use in that sort of situation; it can be analysed, probably several different ways, but it is the way it is.